# List operation in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have this list of type `([(Double,Double)],[(Double,Double)])`. `example list = ([(1.0,1.0), (2.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,3.0)],[(1.0,4.0), (1.0,5.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,2.0), (1.0,3.0), (1.0,4.0), (1.0,5.0)])`

How would I access all the data after the fourth tuple (1.0, 3.0). I have already tried the tail function but doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: i assume the value of the type is correct and your type declaration is not - therefore I adjusted the type

Comment: could you please elaborate what you mean by accessing? Also could you show expected input/output of such a function?

Comment: Is the problem about always accessing all data after the fourth tuple, regardless of how many tuples are in the first list of the outer tuple? Or is it about getting all the data in the second list of the outer tuple?

Answer (score 4):

Well, for one, your list isn't a list, but a tuple :)

```
type MyData = (MyList, MyList)
type MyList = [MyListElem]
type MyListElem = (Double, Double)
```

Now, accessing the 2nd list is simply `snd`.

```
snd :: (a,b) -> b
```

So in your case:

```
snd :: MyData -> MyList
```

---

Alternatively, using `Lens`, you can use a lens on that directly:

```
list ^. _2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a list, but a tuple of lists. In fact, a tuple of lists of tuples.

To get the second part of a tuple, use the [`snd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:snd) command:

```
snd ([(1.0,1.0), (2.0,1.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,3.0)],[(1.0,4.0), (1.0,5.0), (1.0,1.0), (1.0,2.0), (1.0,3.0), (1.0,4.0), (1.0,5.0)])
```

This yields:

```
[(1.0,4.0),(1.0,5.0),(1.0,1.0),(1.0,2.0),(1.0,3.0),(1.0,4.0),(1.0,5.0)]
```

From here on, you can continue to get the parts of the second list using `tail` or the [`!!`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) operator.

For completeness, the first part of a tuple can be obtained using the [`fst`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst) command.